# Perl - Expand a string into a list.

Tags: perl, parsing, templates, cartesian-product

Trying to do something like the following.

```
#expand [a] to is, and isn't
#expand [b] to test, and demo
my $string = 'This [a] a [b]';
```

so basically  I would end up with

```
my @strings = ('This is a test', 'This isn\'t a test', 'This is a demo', 'This isn\'t a demo');
```

I've done this before using recursion but that was on a very big set of data and a lot of rules I feel like there could be an easier way using map or grep or List::MoreUtils I just can't think of it.

Comment: Would an accepted solution for you involve using `s/\[a\]/is/` on `$string`?

Comment: Wouldn't that just modify my original string.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for `sprintf`, if you're not married to the "[a]" thing.

Comment: @ColtonLove Yes, or if you want to create an enclosing block with a temporary variable along with using `map` then that could leave `$string` untouched.

Comment: I am married to the [a] syntax.

Comment: What about `$string = '[a] [a]';`? Should that result in `'test test', 'test demo', 'demo test', 'demo demo'` or just `'test test', 'demo demo'`?

Comment: @ikegami that would be 4 values.

Comment: FYI, what you're looking for is called the Cartesian product or cross product. There are several modules that will determine the Cartesian product; I like Set::CrossProduct since it lets you iterate through the results without loading them all into memory at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given inputs of the form

```
my %dict = (
   a => ["is", "isn't"],
   b => ["test", "demo"],
);

my $template = 'This [a] a [b]';
```

---

Algorithm::Loops version:

```
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );

my @loops;
for ($template) {
   if (/\G \[ /xgc) {
      /\G ( [^\]]* ) \] /xgc
         or die("Missing \"]\"\n");

      my $var = $1;
      length($var)
         or die("Empty \"[]\"\n");

      $dict{$var}      
         or die("Unknown var \"$var\"\n");

      push @loops, $dict{$var};
      redo;
   }

   if (/\G ( [^\[]+ ) /xgc) {
      push @loops, [ $1 ];
      redo;
   }

   /\G \z /xgc
      or die("Internal error");
}

my $iter = NestedLoops(\@loops);
while (my @parts = $iter->()) {
   print(join('', @parts), "\n");
}
```

Output:

```
This is a test
This is a demo
This isn't a test
This isn't a demo
```

---

`glob`-based version:

```
$_ = '{'.join(',', map quotemeta($_), @$_).'}'
   for values(%dict);

my $glob;
for ($template) {
   if (/\G \[ /xgc) {
      /\G ( [^\]]* ) \] /xgc
         or die("Missing \"]\"\n");

      my $var = $1;
      length($var)
         or die("Empty \"[]\"\n");

      $dict{$var}
         or die("Unknown var \"$var\"\n");

      $glob .= $dict{$var};
      redo;
   }

   if (/\G ( [^\[]+ ) /xgc) {
      $glob .= $1;
      redo;
   }

   /\G \z /xgc
      or die("Internal error");
}

while (defined( my $string = glob($glob) )) {
   print($string, "\n");
}
```

---

Without error checking and for that specific dictionary, this can be shrunk quite a bit:

```
$ perl -E'say for glob shift=~s/\[((a)|b)]|(.)/$3?"\Q$3":$1?"{is,isn'\''t}":"{test,demo}"/serg' \
   'This [a] a [b]'
This is a test
This is a demo
This isn't a test
This isn't a demo
```

Comment: I mean that looks almost identical to my first attempt at this. I guess I will just reuse that. I was hoping there could have been a one liner solution.

Comment: You can't expect a oneliner if you invent your own template system.

Comment: Thanks though, you are who I was hoping would respond.

Comment: Added to my answer